# My smartGWT widgets are not displaying propoerly

Tags: smartgwt

I have simply added SmartGWT example in my application.
But the widgets are not coming up properly

Specially the button , Its simply showing the button text ,and not even the structure of button

please have a look

http://screencast.com/t/ddEQQIZLxq

whereas it should be like this

http://screencast.com/t/8SK16Zhggx

any idea, where i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your theme is not properly loaded. Be sure that you are inheriting theme in your `.gwt.xml` file.

From https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Skinning.html

> A skin is implicitly loaded when you add an  tag in your .gwt.xml file to include SmartGWT components (name="com.smartgwt(ee).SmartGWT(Pro|Power|EE)"). To switch skins, add the "NoTheme" suffix to the "name" attribute of this  tag, then add . These tags cause a  tag to be injected into your bootstrap .html page, which loads load_skin.js for the appropriate skin. load_skin.js loads the stylesheet and sets the CSS styleNames and media URLs that Smart GWT components will use.

To inspect your page, you can use firebug and make sure that `skin_styles.css` and `load_skin.js` are loaded.